# Access state from render function

Tags: reactjs, state

So I need to run this line of code:

```
var vehicles = this.state.vehicles;
```

In the render function:

```
render: function(){...}
```

I currently get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of
>   undefined

Even though this line works:

```
this.setState({vehicles: json})
```

This is also part of the code:

```
getInitialState: function(){
    this.render = this.render.bind(this)
    return {
      vehicles: []
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error and access the data?

Comment: Need to see the part of your code where you use those statement. Its difficult to guess otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't bind the render function. I assume that you are creating a component using `React.createClass` since you are using `getInitialState` to initialise the state. With `React.createClass`, React automatically does the binding for you.

Even if you create a component by extending `React.Component`, render method and the lifecycle functions are automatically bound to the React Component context.

Your `getInitialState` function will simply be

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      vehicles: []
    }
  }
```

A sample working snippet

```js
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      console.log(this);
      return {count: 0}
    },
    render: function() {
      return <div>Count:{this.state.count}</div>
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah I thought it should but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I have added a sample working snippet, make sure that you create the component in a similar manner. However I will suggest you to create class by extending React.Component since React.createClass will be deprecaed from v16.x.x onwards

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the initial state, it looks like you didn't, therefore you are getting that error.

```
class YourComponent extends PureComponent {
  state = {}; // <-- Initialize the state
}
```

Or using the constructor

```
class YourComponent extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}; // <-- Initialize the state
  }
}
```

Or using ES5 (Deprecated)

```
var YourComponent = React.createReactClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};  // <-- Initialize the state
  },

  // ...

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `this.setState`, you first have to declare the state variable on `this` reference inside your component.

You do that in the consturctor, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {...};
}
```

You can read more about local state in the React docs: [Adding Local State to a Class](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class).

Comment: From `render: function(){...}` statement it doesn't look like that OP is extending React.Component class

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a context bind problem.

> Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

That means `this` is undefined. I guess you're using it in some change handler. Try to `onChange={this.changeHandler.bind(this)}`.